# Changing properties on UICollectionView Cells from another .xib file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using UICollectionView, and I've added another .xib file apart from the CollectionView called "CollectionItemView". I've used the following in order to display my "CollectionItemView" into the CollectionView:

```
[self.collectionViewPack registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewItem" bundle:nil]
```

Now I've added a few labels and TextViews to the "CollectionViewItem" cell in the interface builder. How Would I call these properties in order to make changes to them in order to assign values to them? Here's the rest of the code in my viewDidLoad of "UICollectionView":

```
forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellReuseIdentifier];
self.collectionViewPack.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[super viewDidLoad];


UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(150, 250)];
[flowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
[self.collectionViewPack setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
[self.collectionViewPack setAllowsSelection:YES];
self.collectionViewPack.delegate=self;
```